# How to put a session in Laravel with Axios?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, axios, session-variables

I work on a project with Laravel and VueJS.

In Laravel, I use only routing API and i call them with Axios in VueJS.

I want to use session but when i put a key, it is not saved.

I added in middlewareGroup :

```
'api' => [
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            

            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
            
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class
        ],
```

To put a session :

```
\Session::put('establishment_id', $establishments[0]->establishment_id);
            $request->session()->put('sp_token', $token);

            //session(['establishment_id' => $establishments[0]->establishment_id,'sp_token' => $token]);

            //TODO WHEN A USER LOGS IN, CHOOSE WHICH ESTABLISHMENT HE WANTS TO WORK WITH
            //IN FRONT-END, SWITCH EHPAD, RESIDENCE... AND CHANGE SESSION DATA

            //$establishments  = EstablishmentUser::where('user_id',$currentUser->id)->get();
            // if(count($establishments)==1){
            // } else if (count($establishments)>=1){
            //     //NEED TO CHOOSE ESTABLISHMENT
            // }

            return response()->json(['msg' => 'success'], 200)->header('Authorization', $token);
```

and when i do :

```
dd(Session::all())
```

there is only _token: value and not my other session.

I modified in config/session : file to database but there is always this problem.

2 questions :  is-it possible to use session in API ?
If yes, how can i resolve this problem ?

Sorry for my english.
Thanks for your answer !

Comment: What did you add to `middlewareGroup`? Where is this code located?

Comment: from where are you doing `dd(Session::all())` from inside a blade php or from a vue component, though you can't use php sessions in vue, you need to use local storage instead

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I add a session in my Controller (for example, the controller which handles the authentication).

Comment: Thank you for your answer !

@bhucho : I added dd(Session:::all), in my middleware. I don't use blade, i use only component. But i didn't right php in my component in vuejs.

Comment: if your frontend is completely separate & variables are passed using api, then you can't use php sessions in js, you need to use local storage (cookies sometimes)

Comment: @bhucho I don't want use session in js. I want use session inside my back-end only

Comment: then what is you laravel version as session syntax has changed from old laravel to new

Comment: It is the version 7.28.3 and in the doc it is Session::put() or $request->session()->put() or session()->put() to add a session

Comment: An i tested, before the send my response to my vue, my session is stored. But when i write dd in another controller, there are nothing.

Comment: I tested, to add a session in my middleware, it is ok. But in another controller not.
So, with api route, can't we put a session ?